# Scala.JS generated module throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined"

Tags: scala.js

I've compiled a simple Scala class to JavaScript using Scala.JS, and I want to import it to a JavaScript code, but importing it throws the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
    at scalajsenv.js:39
```

I've replaced the generated script with a simple script that defines the same class and exports it. it worked so I am sure that the problem is on the Scala.JS side.

Scala class:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("SomeClass")
@ScalaJSDefined
class SomeClass(i: Int) extends js.Object
```

build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

name := "scalajs-example"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
scalacOptions += "-P:scalajs:sjsDefinedByDefault"

scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.ESModule) }
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.27")
```

The JavaScript file that imports the generated code:

```
import { SomeClass } from  "./target/scala-2.12/scalajs-example-fastopt.js"
```